# Browser plugin/extension/addon to see id of all elements at once

Tags: google-chrome-extension, attributes, firefox-addon, overlay

*Despite extensive Google search I haven't been able to find what I was looking for, so I'm hoping experienced SO users will have an answer.*

I am looking for a `Firefox` or `Chrome` plugin that can automatically display elements' `id` attribute value inside an overlay on top of the actual elements. For instance:

[image]

The idea is to be able to have a quick snapshot of what `id` attributes are used within a page and where, instead of having to go through the entire page manually with tools such as Firebug or Firefox/Chrome's DOM inspectors (which only allow you to see elements one by one, not have a full picture).

**Does anybody know a `Firefox` / `Chrome` plugin that can do that?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Web Developer" extension for Firefox / Chrome includes this feature. The option can be toggled by clicking on "Information -> Display Anchors".

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm

## In Firefox

[image]

## In Chrome

[image]

## Result

[image]

Instead of installing an extra extension, you could also enter `$$('[id]')` in the console, which results in a list of all elements with an "id" attribute.

Comment: Great stuff, and almost sad how I missed it. Also, very nice console trick.

Comment: A while back I've also published a specialized extension for this purpose. Its main advantage over the Web Developer extension is that the layout of the page does not change, see: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/display-anchors/poahndpaaanbpbeafbkploiobpiiieko

Comment: @RobW I tried your extension, but the layout broke completely. Granted, I tried it with a webapp and not some website with mainly web content.

Comment: @Ashnur My extension = the one linked in my comment, or in my answer? The one in my comment is supposed to *not* change the layout, so if you found a bug, I'll happily try to fix it and publish an update.

Comment: @RobW the one in your comment. I will get back later with an example.